# Regex to match any character or fullstop?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that takes a filename like:

```
/cloud-support/filename.html#pagesection
```

and redirects it to:

```
/cloud-platform/filename#pagesection
```

Could anyone advise how to do this?

Currently I've got part-way there, with:

```
"^/cloud-support/(.*)$" => "/cloud-platform/$1",
```

which redirects the directory okay - but still has a superfluous `.html`.

Could I just match for a literal `.html` with optional `#`? How would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an URL rewrite, i.e. apache's mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes - actually using lighttpd but I think it's similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
"^/cloud-support/(.*?)(\.html)?(#.+)$" => "/cloud-platform/$1$3"
```

where the first group is a non-greedy match (.*?)

Comment: That won't match /cloud-support/filename.html# or even /cloud-support/filename.html

Comment: Worked very nicely - the only change I made was to make all parameters optional, i.e. `"^/cloud-support/(.*?)?(\.html)?(#.+)?$" => "/cloud-platform/$1$3"`. Thanks!

Comment: ... @BobVale amended version is okay, I think.

Comment: It will, if you use Python. But it might depend on the particular type of regular expression.

Comment: @Richard - `/cloud-support/filename.html#` still won't match change to `"^/cloud-support/(.*?)(\.html)?(#.*)?$" => "/cloud-platform/$1$3"` to make the chars after the # optional you also didn't need the ? after (.*?) because (.*?) can match the empty string

Comment: Actually `/cloud-support/filename.html#` will match but would put the entire match in $1

Answer (score 0):

```
"^/cloud-support/(\w+).html(.*)" => "/cloud-platform/$1$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
"^/cloud-support/([^.]+)[^#]*(.*)$" => "/cloud-platform/$1$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the regex

```
"^/cloud-support/(.*)\.html(#.*)?$"
```

The `\.html` part matches `.html` while `(#.*)?` allows an optional `#` plus something.